# Limitations of using a single ec2 instance to deploy a database

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My application requires **MongoDB** to run. I was wondering if you could explain the limitations of using a single **ec2** instance to deploy a database.

What would be a couple other options that wouldn't require **ec2?**

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic options:

1. Run your own instance of MongoDB on EC2, or in a container.
2. Use a managed service such as [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/register) or [DocumentDB](https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/)

The first option provides you with more control of the application and its runtime environment, and more flexibility in configuration.

The downside is the overhead imposed in the management of the solution: Upgrades, scaling,  performance, configuration changes, security patches. And this applies to the underliying operating system as well.

Comment: What about DocumentDB? Probably worth mentioning it